# Unity toggle state change causes StackOverflow

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm instantiating a Toggle based on a prefab in my Start method. However when I click the toggle Unity freezes and I see a StackOverflow pop up in the Console. I'm following this [Unity toggle example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Toggle-onValueChanged.html).

I have a hunch my error is because after creating the Toggle I pass `tog` to another method that creates an instance (because I need a lot of toggles in my program), but I don't understand why it is crashing. Can someone explain it?

```
public void Start(){
//toggle creation
    GameObject tog1 = Instantiate(prefabTog, btnVector + Vector3.left * 90, Quaternion.identity);
    tog1.transform.SetParent(imgBtnParent.transform, false);
    Toggle tog = tog1.GetComponent<Toggle>();
    tog.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate {ToggleValueChanged(tog);});

//generate toggle instance on screen and pass me back a Scriptable Object
var so=GenerateItem.CreateInstance(tog);
}

public class GenerateItem: ScriptableObject {
        public Toggle AutoTog=null;
            public static GenerateItem(Toggle tog){
            GenerateItem o = CreateInstance<GenerateItem>();
            o.AutoTog=tog;
         }
}
```

**Toggle on Change**

```
public void ToggleValueChanged(Toggle t)
{
    t.isOn = !t.isOn;
}
```

Comment: I was about about to answer this but then found the exact duplicate that I've answered before. You need `ToggleGroup`